# Visual Studio Template for Static Azure Apps

Tags: visual-studio, azure-static-web-app

I have been looking into the Azure Static Apps and its seems to work ok.

Is there a template for static apps. I mean I have my website in a folder but opening that in visual studio means there is no debug support.

If I choose the web app template then we get all the ASP.NET stuff like references etc. So, is there a template or a preferred pattern that is being missed.

Comment: We are planning to add support for creating and deploying Blazor WebAssembly and Azure Functions apps to Azure Static Web Apps. However there’s no ETA at this time.

Comment: I think my comment was not well understood.

Comment: Any updates? Anyone?